# Turning a bunch of codes into loop Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, button, tkinter

I want to draw tictactoe board using buttons through python tkinter. But I found my code inefficient. Could anyone please help me converting the codes into loops?

```
import tkinter as tk
main = tk.Tk()

box1 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text1, width=15, height=5)
box1.grid(row=0, column=0)
box2 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text2, width=15, height=5)
box2.grid(row=0, column=1)
box3 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text3, width=15, height=5)
box3.grid(row=0, column=2)
box4 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text4, width=15, height=5)
box4.grid(row=1, column=0)
box5 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text5, width=15, height=5)
box5.grid(row=1, column=1)
box6 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text6, width=15, height=5)
box6.grid(row=1, column=2)
box7 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text7, width=15, height=5)
box7.grid(row=2, column=0)
box8 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text8, width=15, height=5)
box8.grid(row=2, column=1)
box9 = tk.Button(main, textvariable = box_text9, width=15, height=5)
box9.grid(row=2, column=2)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you

```
import tkinter as tk
main = tk.Tk()

boxes_list = []
for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
                box = tk.Button(main, textvariable = "box_text" + str(i*3 + j + 1), width=15, height=5)
                box.grid(row=i, column=j)
                boxes_list.append(box)
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some new things:

- Code to calculate box coordinates
- two lists to store all the boxes and textvariables

**Coordinate calculation**

```
row = num_box // 3
col = num_box % 3
```

**List**

```
boxes = []
vars = []
```

The rest is easy:

```
for num_box in range(9):
    row = num_box // 3
    col = num_box % 3
    textvar = tk.StringVar()
    box = tk.Button(main, textvariable = textvar, width=15, height=5)
    box.grid(row=row, column=col)
    boxes.append(box)
    vars.append(textvar)
```